# How to write a struct to a file using dynamic memory allocation in C

Tags: c, struct, malloc, fwrite

I'm trying to write a program that takes n amount of Students from a user, stores them in a struct, and then stores them in a file.

When I try to store the elements in a file, it just seems to collect the name, and a ton of garbage.

I think the problem might be how I'm allocating memory, but I'm not certain.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Student {
    char name[32];
    int number;
    float gpa;
}sArray[100];

//Global variables
int totalStudents;
int i;

//Reads From the User
//a number of records to read
//b all records (name, number, gpa)
//c return list of students - TODO!

struct Student getStudents(){
    //Get number of elements
    printf("Enter Number of Students: ");
        scanf("%d", &totalStudents);
    sArray[totalStudents];
    printf("You Entered: %d\n", totalStudents);

    for(i=0;i<totalStudents;i++){
        printf("Enter Student %d Name: \n", i+1);
        scanf("%s", sArray[i].name);
        printf("Enter Student %d Number: \n", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &sArray[i].number);
        printf("Enter Student %d GPA: \n", i+1);
        scanf("%f", &sArray[i].gpa);
    }

    //Allocate memory
    struct Student *ptr;
    ptr = (struct Student*) malloc(totalStudents * sizeof(struct Student));
    free(ptr);
}

//Writes records to a File called student.db
int writeToFile(){
    FILE *fp;

    if((fp = fopen("student.db", "wb")) == NULL){
        puts("Error, File Could Not Be Opened.");
    }
    else{
        for(i=0;i<totalStudents;i++){
            fwrite(&sArray[i], sizeof(sArray[i]), 1, fp);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);

}

//Switch Function - TODO!

//Print Function
struct Student displayStudents(){
    for(i=0;i<totalStudents;i++){
        printf("%s   %d   %.2f\n", sArray[i].name, sArray[i].number, sArray[i].gpa);
    }
}
//Main
int main(){
    getStudents();
    writeToFile();
    displayStudents();

    return 0;

}
```

If my input values are {1, Dychii, 123, 4} It writes this to the file:

[Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHL4a.jpg)

Comment: You can't see 123 and 4.0 as they are in a text editor in standart mode. Even if you open the file in hex mode, integers can have different byte and bit order then you expect. Floats in memory is whole other story.

Comment: This line `sArray[totalStudents];` does nothing as long as `totalStudents` is `<100` else it provokes undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

However long your name in struct it will write 32 chars for name 4 bytes for int and 4 bytes for float. The characters after null terminator in a string does not mater. In your case "Dychii\0" 7 character, 25 character after that is not important.

By the way instead of

```
fwrite(&sArray[i], sizeof(sArray[i]), 1, fp);
```

you can say

```
fwrite(&sArray[i], sizeof(Student), 1, fp);
```

which will be slightly more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You are writing to a binary file. That means that you create a file that is identical to the way data is stored in memory. It also means that you can't open the file in a normal editor and make any sense of it. With a hex editor you may be able to understand it if you know how variables are stored in memory.

If you want to store the file in text mode so that you can open it in a normal editor, you can try something like this:

```
//Writes records to a File called student.db
void writeToFile(){
    FILE *fp;

    if((fp = fopen("student.db", "w")) == NULL){   //Note: only w
        puts("Error, File Could Not Be Opened.");
    }
    else{
        for(i=0;i<totalStudents;i++){
            fprintf(fp, "%s ", sArray[i].name);
            fprintf(fp, "%d ", sArray[i].number);
            fprintf(fp, "%f\n", sArray[i].gpa);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Besides that you have some code problems:

1) `sArray[totalStudents];` has no effect - just delete it

2) The functions `getStudents`, `writeToFile` and `displayStudents` never returns anything even though you say they should. Maybe you really want them to be `void`

**Dynamic memory**

You say you want to use dynamic memory. But currently you don't. This code:

```
//Allocate memory
struct Student *ptr;
ptr = (struct Student*) malloc(totalStudents * sizeof(struct Student));
free(ptr);
```

allocates some memory and then frees it again. In other words - the code does nothing. In fact you are currently just using the global `sArray` all places.

If you want to use dynamic memory, you should start by doing this change:

```
struct Student {
    char name[32];
    int number;
    float gpa;
};  // Get rid of global variable sArray[100];
```

Then you need to change all places in the rest of the code where you currently use `sArray`.

One example:

```
struct Student* getStudents(){   // Return a pointer to struct Student
    //Get number of elements
    printf("Enter Number of Students: ");
    scanf("%d", &totalStudents);
    printf("You Entered: %d\n", totalStudents);

    // Allocate memory
    struct Student* ptr;
    ptr = malloc(totalStudents * sizeof(struct Student));

    for(i=0;i<totalStudents;i++){
        printf("Enter Student %d Name: \n", i+1);
        scanf("%s", ptr[i].name);
        printf("Enter Student %d Number: \n", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &(ptr[i].number));
        printf("Enter Student %d GPA: \n", i+1);
        scanf("%f", &(ptr[i].gpa));
    }

    return ptr;    // Return a pointer to struct Student
}
```

Hope this will give you an idea for updating the other code parts.

Final comment: You should add error checking. That is

a) always check the value returned by `scanf`

b) always check the value returned by `malloc`

Comment: @bad22 - answer updated regarding use of dynamic memory